# GameObject has no definition for transform in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to make this code works, and whatever I do it just keeps telling me that it's impossible. So I am trying to get this GameObject (that I have defined before in the script) called block to have a parent with the tag Terrain. This is the code:

```
block.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Terrain").transform);
```

The error message I get reads:

> 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no accessible extension method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp] csharp(CS1061)```

Comment: use `FindWithTag` command istead, docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Comment: thank you so much Nikolay, i owe you one

Comment: well an array has no `transform` ;) ... and don't use **any** of the `Find` methods if you can avoid it ... best option would be to reference the according `GameObject` or `Transform` via the Inspector e.g. in a `[SerializeField] private Transform terrainTransform;` using Drag&Drop

Answer (score 0):

[FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) returns an array containing all the GameObjects with the specified tag. In your case, you need to use [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) which returns the first element founded with the specified tag.

```cs
block.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain").transform);
```